# Laravel / Voyager Issue

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, voyager

I am facing this issue while installing Voyager, it won't let me either create or install voyager.
I tried changing everything.

[image]

Can somebody help please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrCGO.png

Comment: It would be better to post the console output as text and at full length.

Comment: Git is probably missing, or if you have it installed you haven't added it to the default path.
Also on Windows you can use Git bash console hat gets installed when you install git

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't installed `git` so the command is not available to clone the voyager repository.

Comment: Thanks, ima try to install it and get it back to you.